# How to get EAN with more than 13 numbers to be excluded (PHP)

Tags: php

I made this script for a website, where it basically synchronizes with the supplier. Now my issue is that the supplier started to provide more than one EAN per product. I need to have the script check if the product has more than 1 ean (one ean contains 13 numbers) and if it has more than 13 numbers that it only takes the first 13 digits of the ean. I can't find any solution

```php
update_post_meta( $id, '_sku', $ean);
update_post_meta( $id, 'productcode', $bfc);
update_post_meta( $id, '_stock', $qty);
update_post_meta( $id, '_price', $selling_price);
update_post_meta( $id, '_regular_price', $selling_price);
wp_untrash_post($id);
#update_post_meta($id, 'channable_sync', 1);
if ($qty > 0) {
  update_post_meta($id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
} else {
update_post_meta($id, '_stock_status', 'outofstock');
}
if ($ean ==> 13) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For checking whether the EAN is >=13 chars you use `strlen()` and for the first 13 chars you use `preg_match()` and a regexp expression (`(\d{13})`).

```php
<?php
$ean = "123456789012345";

if(strlen($ean) >= 13) {
  echo "yes more than 13 chars\n";
}

preg_match('/(\d{13})/', $ean, $matches);

echo $matches[0];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not seem to work.. I tried applying this but no success. Seems like it is not executing the script at the moment

Comment: What data type is your $ean? My script snippet is working perfectly with a string.

Comment: Its a string, but maybe I am writing it wrong within my code. This is how it looks like now: https://pastebin.com/Sy1WZwpF

Comment: I need it to detect if the supplier is giving an ean longer than 13 numbers, and that if that is true that it then excludes all numbers after the 13 numbers and keeps that specific product ean number for that specific product which it found to have more than 13 number ean with.. if that makes any sense

Comment: You didn't assign the reg exp to a variable. See $matches in my example. It's an array with all the regexp matches grouped by () in /(\d{13})/'. In this example you only have one value in $matches[0].

Comment: Hmm I don't think that the eans are strings, that could be the reason why its not working.. This is how one product with more than one ean looks: https://i.gyazo.com/7301793922f607cb26da65a9bb5d6721.png

Comment: you could check that with var_dump()

Answer (score 0):

To avoid double writes to db, first check if $ean is longer than 13 digits (characters), if yes then truncate it to 13 digits, then store it in db

```
if(strlen($ean) > 13){
   //is longer than 13
   $ean = substr($ean, 0, 13); //truncate to 13 chars
}
update_post_meta( $id, '_sku', $ean);
update_post_meta( $id, 'productcode', $bfc);

//the rest of your code
```

or one-liner instead: `$ean = strlen($ean) > 13 ? substr($ean, 0, 13) : $ean;`

I assume that your $ean is type of string or integer equal or less than PHP_INT_MAX

Comment: @AlessioFlorio If it's working for you, please consider marking my answer as accepted (green check mark on the left side of the answer)

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work, could it be that the ean is not a string? the eans with more than one look like this: 3274872320161, 3274872366053, 3274872383753, 3274872300477, 3274872268029. They all have comma's in them. Take these for example: https://i.gyazo.com/7301793922f607cb26da65a9bb5d6721.png Any idea on what it could be? I will upvote once it works :)

Comment: The look tells nothing about the type. If it was string or integer (like in my answer) it would work.  What does `var_dump($ean);` return?